# Image stored in SQL Server to ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have stored image into SQL Server, which is in format `0x5B42403432323863653230`.

I used handler, it is not displaying the image. The image is of very small size. Can I directly convert the bytes into image in ASP.NET instead of a Handler?

Comment: Can you add your code to save and display the image?

Comment: DECLARE 
@SIGNATURE VARCHAR(MAX)=NULL,

INSERT
cast(@SIGNATURE as image)